# Python PyPDF2 merge rotated pages

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab, pypdf

I'm using python [ReportLab](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/) canvas to generate overlay document with watermarks to merge it into source pdf document (with [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2)). Recently I encountered a problem with a document that contains rotated pages (/Rotate key is present for Page object in pdf). This document looks ok on devices and printers. But result (merged) document contains  watermarks that were rotated against source document.

So source page has next structure in pdf:

```
6 0 obj
<</Length 45>>
stream
q
1 0 0 1 2 4 cm
799 0 0 603 0 0 cm
/x5 Do
Q

endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources << /XObject << /x5 5 0 R >> >>
/MediaBox [0 0 792 612]
/Rotate 270/Contents 6 0 R
>>
endobj
```

As you can see page rotated by 270 degrees.

I'm using similar script to generate and merge watermark and source page:

```py
from six import BytesIO
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas

# Set page rotation
rotation_angle = 270
# Render watermark layer
stream = BytesIO()
c = Canvas(stream, pagesize=A4)
if rotation_angle:
    c.setPageRotation(rotation_angle)
c.drawString(1 * inch, 8 * inch, "Hello World! " * 3)
c.showPage()
c.save()

stream.seek(0)
overlay = PdfFileReader(stream)
source = PdfFileReader(u'test.pdf')
writer = PdfFileWriter()

# Merge sorce and watermark pages
page0 = source.getPage(0)
if rotaion_angle:
    page0.mergeRotatedPage(overlay.getPage(0), rotation_angle, True)
else:
    page0.mergePage(overlay.getPage(0))
writer.insertPage(page0, 0)

# Write result to file
with open('merged.pdf', 'wb') as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
print "Done!"
```

This way for `rotation_angle = 270` I've got next result: [screenshot](http://monosnap.com/image/URyr6faJRlZV6fk3KmjyCh9VxA5MIH)

And for `rotation_angle = 0` (don't care about rotation at all) I've got: [screenshot](http://monosnap.com/image/c2BcwCzH8vqpRfOcYiAGOnC7CmaIZE)

How can I change script to fix this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I found similar problem and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041244/how-to-merge-two-landscape-pdf-pages-using-pypdf/17392824#17392824)

So I changed code in next way

```py
# Merge source and watermark pages
page0 = source.getPage(0)
over0 = overlay.getPage(0)
if rotaion_angle:
    page0.mergeRotatedAroundPointPage(
        over0,
        rotaion_angle,
        over0.mediaBox.getWidth() / 2,
        over0.mediaBox.getWidth() / 2)

    #page0.mergeRotatedPage(overlay.getPage(0), rotaion_angle, True)
else:
    page0.mergePage(over0)
```

Method [mergeRotatedAroundPointPage](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L1921) do the trick.

Comment: This solved my issue, however as of v1.23, mergeRotatedAroundPointPage was renamed to mergeRotatedTranslatedPage. This is not mentioned in the change logs in case anyone else is stuck wondering why. See issue: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/174