# Text rotated when merging pdf pages using Pypdf2 and Reportlab

Tags: python, image, pdf, reportlab, pypdf

I'm trying to merge two pages
one from reportlab that has the text I wish and another one is my source pdf

But when I merge those two pages, my text is rotated 90 degree

Pdf created using Report lab -> [Overlay Created using Reportlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLm1w.png)

when Merged with Source pdf -> [Source Pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9y2C.png)

Code that I have Used :

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

packet = io.BytesIO()
c = canvas.Canvas(packet)
c.drawString(0,0,"Hello World")
c.save()
packet.seek(0)

packet_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
input_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("Source.pdf", "rb"))

output = PdfFileWriter()
page = input_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(packet_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)

outputStream = open("destination.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

reference : [Add text to Existing PDF using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refered to this and created an own solution -> [Python PyPDF2 merge rotated pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631755/python-pypdf2-merge-rotated-pages?rq=1)

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas

page_to_merge = 0 #Refers to the First page of PDF 
xcoor = 250 #To be changed according to your pdf
ycoor = 650 #To be changed according to your pdf

input_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("Source.pdf", "rb"))
page_count = input_pdf.getNumPages()
inputpdf_page_to_be_merged = input_pdf.getPage(page_to_merge)

packet = io.BytesIO()
c = Canvas(packet,pagesize=(inputpdf_page_to_be_merged.mediaBox.getWidth(),inputpdf_page_to_be_merged.mediaBox.getHeight()))
c.drawString(xcoor,ycoor,"Hello World")
c.save()
packet.seek(0)

overlay_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
overlay = overlay_pdf.getPage(0)

output = PdfFileWriter()

for PAGE in range(page_count):
    if PAGE == page_to_merge:
        inputpdf_page_to_be_merged.mergeRotatedTranslatedPage(overlay, 
                inputpdf_page_to_be_merged.get('/Rotate') or 0, 
                overlay.mediaBox.getWidth()/2, overlay.mediaBox.getWidth()/2)
        output.addPage(inputpdf_page_to_be_merged)
    
    else:
        Page_in_pdf = input_pdf.getPage(PAGE)
        output.addPage(Page_in_pdf)

outputStream = open("destination.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).